# How to communicate with a running Docker container in a Host X from another Host Y(not from a container in Host Y)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am experimenting about Docker-networking, I had set up a scenario as below,

Installed docker in a host-X connected over a network (host-X IP: 60.0.0.28) and run a basic docker container of ubuntu-OS (Docker Container is connected to the default docker bridge network only i.e. 172.17.0.0/16 & 172.17.0.2 is container IP). Now trying to communicate that running container from another host-Y with in the same network (host-Y IP: 60.0.0.40) in which no docker is installed.

I had added basic route in host-Y like, "ip route add 172.17.0.0/16 via 60.0.0.28 dev ens3" .

From the container i am able to ping the Host-Y & in reverse case, i am only able to ping the docker gateway "172.17.0.1" from Host-Y but not able to reach the container.

Comment: If you try to communicate from outside a container network to a container by its container ip, it is high likely you are doing something wrong. The intended solution for what you try to do is to publish container ports to host ports. See https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports for more details regarding published ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a wide variety of situations where the Docker-internal IP addresses just aren't useful; calling from a different host is one of them.  You should totally ignore those as an implementation detail.

If you take Docker out of the picture, and run the process directly on the host, this should be straightforward: from host Y, you can call the process on host X given its DNS name and the port the server is running on.

```
hostY$ curl http://hostX:12345/
```

If the process is actually running in a Docker container, you need to make sure you've started the container with a published port.  This doesn't necessarily need to match the port the process is listening on.

```
hostX$ docker run -p 12345:12345 imagename
```

Once you've done this, the process can be reached via the host's DNS name or IP address, and the published port, the same way as with a non-container server.

In normal circumstances you should not need to think about the Docker-internal IP addresses; you do not need manual `ip` route-setup commands like you show, and you shouldn't `docker inspect` or `docker run --ip` to find or set this detail.

Comment: Thanks @David Maze for the detailed explanation, i got a very good understanding about this docker-networking.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s assume you want to start Dockerized nginx on host X.

You’d run:

```
docker run --detach -p 8080:80 nginx
```

Then you could access your nginx instance using `http://60.0.0.28:8080`.

Comment: Thanks Kanrad, it helped to communicate with the container from external hosts. But my point what i want to know is Whether can we communicate directly with container IP from other hosts or that case is not possible ???